# Comando "find" eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

[image: Janela "desfoca" código]

Sempre quando abro uma janela, todo editor fica "ofuscado" dificultando a leitura, alguém já passou por isso e consegue me ajudar?

Comment: está utilizando o ubuntu?

Comment: Sim, utilizo ubuntu

Comment: isso aí provavelmente não é relacionado ao eclipse não, utilizo aqui no windows e não acontece, alguns temas do linux deixam esse fundo branco, é só alterar

Comment: é isso mesmo, muito obrigado, posta isso como resposta amigo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme comentado, alguns temas do Ubuntu dão esse efeito de blur no fundo, não sendo diretamente ligado ao Eclipse, sendo necessário apenas [alterá-lo](https://www.edivaldobrito.com.br/mudar-o-tema-e-conjunto-de-icones-padrao-do-ubuntu/).

Comment: Muito obrigado! Era esse o problema.